# Why can't I initialize a global variable from another global variable containing an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables

index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="1script.js" defer></script>
<title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1" name="userInputForm"> 
   <label for="moq">MOQ:</label><br>
   <input type="number" id="moq" name="moq" onfocusout=""><br>
<br>

<div id="calculate"><input type="button" name="button" style="width: 8rem; height: 2rem;" value="Calulate"  onClick="priceResults()"></div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

scripts.js file

```
var userInputFormm = document.getElementById("form1");
//var whatMoq = userInputFormm.moq.value;

 function priceResults(){
   alert(userInputFormm.moq.value);
    }
```

This code as you can see runs perfectly as below.
[image]

but when I assign `userInputFormm.moq.value` to a variable `whatMoq` there is no result as I believe `whatMoq` is not able to access `userInputForm`. as shown below in my scripts.js and results

[image]

but if I create the `whatMoq` variable in the function `priceResults()`, it works like below

[image]
[image]

I want to create different functions for the same set of variables. but this problem makes me initialize the same set of variables as local variables to every function I create, which is pretty tiring because in my project, I have quite a handful of variables and my codes look to many.

[image]
[image]
it is not accessing the `whatMoq` variables to add the numbers.

but if I make the `whatMoq` variables local, it works perfectly.

[image]
[image]

so if I want to create multiple functions with these `whatMoq` variables, then I will have to initialize them everytime as local variables.

Is this really the only way?

Answer (score 1):

The javascript (script.js) file that you have added with help of  is only executed once when the page loads.

At that time what you have done is

1. Saved the reference of the element with id form1 in a variable **userInputFormm**.
2. Created variable with **whatMoq** and assigned with value
   **userInputFormm.moq.value;**.
3. But initially your **userInputForm** form object has moq input field with no initial value. (i.e. "" as its a input element with type as text).

So when js file get compiled and run, you have variable referencing to that form and variable with whatMoq with initial value as empty string ("").

But when you type something in input field. The userInputFormm object's moq element value property get updated internally.

And when you click on calculate priceResults function get called ,

1. In first case you have reference of userInputFormm object, which has internally updated the value.So when you alert you will see the value as per input.
2. But in second case you are not updating the whatMoq value anywhere , and js file does not re-run, thats why you are getting value as initial value i.e "" which is showing nothing on screen as its empty.

To make it work you can do like.

scrip.js

```
var userInputFormm = document.getElementById("form1");
var whatMoq = userInputFormm.moq.value;
//CREATED ANOTHER VARIABLE TO THE INPUT I ADDED
var whatMoq1 = userInputFormm.moq1.value;

function handleMoqChange(e){
    whatMoq = e.target.value;
}

//FUNCTION TO HANDLE THE CHANGE OF THE NEW INPUT ELEMENT'S CHANGE
function handleMoq1Change(e){
    whatMoq1 = parseInt(e.target.value);
}

//NEW VARIABLE FOR MATH
var total = whatMoq + whatMoq1;

 function priceResults(){
  //alert(userInputFormm.moq.value);
  alert(total);
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="1script.js" defer></script>
<title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1" name="userInputForm"> 
   <label for="moq">MOQ:</label><br>
   <input onChange="handleMoqChange(event)" type="number" id="moq" name="moq" onfocusout=""><br>
<br>

<!--ADDED ANOTHER HTML INPUT-->
        <label for="moq">MOQ1:</label><br>
        <input type="number" onChange="handleMoq1Change(event)" id="moq1" name="moq1" onfocusout=""><br>
        <br>

<div id="calculate">
<input type="button" name="button" style="width: 8rem; height: 2rem;" value="Calulate"  onClick="priceResults()">
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for explaining in details.

this works yes, but when I add another input element and assign it to a variable in script.js. after handling the change, if I try to do math calculations with the variables again, it returns an empty string again. like below

Comment: let me edit the codes you posted as answer, so you check it out for me

Comment: I have made changes to the code you submitted as an answer. @Shivprasad Bele 

if I do not assign `moq+moq1`  to `total` and I print out `moq+moq1` directly, it will work.

Comment: can you please share updated code snippet? So I will get an idea what is the issue

Answer (score 1):

```js
var userInputFormm = document.getElementById("form1");
var whatMoq = userInputFormm.moq.value;
```

In line 2, the value for `userInputFormm.moq.value` isn't defined, so when you assign it to the variable `whatMoq`, you assign the undefined value to the `whatMoq`. try console logging the `userInputFormm.moq.value` at line 2, and see the result.

If you want to assign the input value to a variable, it has to be after the input value has been updated, that's why it works when you bring line 2 into the `priceResults()` function.

If you need the value in a global variable, you can define the variable and update it later when the input has value. For example:

```js
var userInputFormm = document.getElementById("form1");
var whatMoq = null;

function priceResults() {
  whatMoq = userInputFormm.moq.value;
  alert(whatMoq)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are:

1. Copying the value of the input to `whatMoq`. This is an empty string because you've done it before step 2.
2. Typing in the input which changes its value from an empty string to whatever you typed.
3. Calling the `priceResults` function
4. Alerting the value of `whatMoq`

`whatMoq` is a **copy** of the value when you copy it and not a **reference** to the current value.

You need to pay attention to the passage of linear time and the order in whcih things happen.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand your answer, perhaps if you can explain it further with codes? you stated the problems without solutions

Comment: You already have two versions of code, one of which works, and one of which doesn't. The one that doesn't work doesn't work for for the reasons described in this answer. I can't make it any simpler then walking you through step by step. The solution is explained in the last sentence of this answer (and is the same as doing what you do in the code you already have that works).

Comment: the code that works will let me initialize the same local variables every time I create a function. that is what I am trying to prevent. I want to initialize all variables as global with the userInputFormm so that they can be accessed by every function I create.

Comment: because when I make `whatMoq` as a local variable to the function `priceResults()` the code works. but say if I have to create a lot of variables. I will have to create the same local variables for each function I create @Quentin